# Match all [A-Z] but not duplicates

Tags: python, regex

I need to match all upper case letters in a string, but not duplicates of the same letter in python I've been using

```
from re import compile

regex = compile('[A-Z]')
variables = regex.findall('(B or P) and (P or not Q)')
```

but that will match ['B', 'P', 'P', 'Q'] but I need ['B', 'P', 'Q'].

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to not match strings with duplicates, or you just want to filter duplicates from your results?  If the latter, use a `set`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative lookahead with a backreference to avoid matching duplicates:

```
re.findall(r'([A-Z])(?!.*\1.*$)', '(B or P) and (P or not Q)')
```

This returns:

```
['B', 'P', 'Q']
```

Comment: I think this is the "correct" answer

Comment: Just https://xkcd.com/208/.

Answer (score 0):

And if order matters do:

```
print(sorted(set(variables),key=variables.index))
```

Or if you have the `more_itertools` package:

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen as u
print(u(variables))
```

Or if version >= 3.6:

```
print(list({}.fromkeys(variables)))
```

Or `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(variables)))
```

All reproduce:

```
['B', 'P', 'Q']
```